# How can I prevent multiple instances of an object from having the same attributes in Java

Tags: java, oop

Below is my code snippet

```
Account acc1 = new Account ("123", "James", "Savings");
Account acc2 = new Account ("234", "James", "Checking");
acc1.setNickName("James Account");
acc2.setNickName("James Account");


//Nick Name Method
private String nickName;

public void setNickName (String name)
{
    nickname = name;

}
```

My question is how can I prevent `acc2` object from having the value of NickName same as that of `acc1`?

I want to ensure that in the `setNickName` method there is a mechanism to prevent two object instances from being the same.

Comment: You can override `equals` and `hashCode`

Comment: Not sure but override `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in `Account` class.

Comment: Could you expound on this suggestion please?

Comment: could you then please show us the `setNickName()` definition?

Comment: @C.Peck:  Seriously??  It's a **setter**.  You don't need to see `setNickName(String nickName)`, do you?

Comment: OP wants to make changes to that function so I asked to see the function.  I would of course expect it to be a simple setter but the asker wants to "ensure that in the setNickName method there is a mechanism to prevent two object instances from being the same."

Comment: The mechanism for preventing duplicate nicknames shouldn't be in the Account class. It should be in whatever the thing is that holds the collection of accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a static `Set` object in your `Account` class and every time a `nickname` is added, you check if already one exists. If it doesn't, then set the value. If it doesn't exists, then you can have your own logic(I have thrown a `IllegalArgumentException`)

```
class Account {

private static Set<String> nickNameSet = new HashSet<>();

public void setNickName(String nickName) {
    if(nickNameSet.add(nickName))
    {
    this.nickName = nickName;
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nick Name already exists");
    }
  }
}
```

As pointed out by @Makoto, defining the `Set` object in the `Account` class will lead to all account object having access to nickname of other accounts. If data hiding is your concern, we should create a new class say `AccountManager` and have the logic of identifying duplicate `nickName` delegated to it.

Comment: I thought about this but the issue here is one of information hiding.  You now have every account aware of every *other* account's nickname.  This is useful in a pinch but breaks a lot of layers of separation.  Supposing then we needed to check for unique IDs next; how could we accomplish this with that?  (And I know that's not a constraint here but it's food for thought.)

Comment: Changing the field to `private` doesn't make those objects any less aware, since every `Account` instance has direct access to that field.

Comment: @Makoto Got your point. I have defined the `Set` in the same `Account` class. What you have done is define a new `AccountManager` class and define this `Set(Collection)` there and have logic for assigning nickname delegated there. A simple thing but makes a lot of difference in regards to data hiding. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

It's not as simple as *just* overriding `equals` or `hashCode` in your `Account` object.  By specifying a constraint on two distinct instances of `Account`, this implies that both instances are **aware** of one another.  In this context, they're not going to be; they're two independent instances which really *shouldn't* be aware of each other in reality.

What you're going to have to do is have some kind of account manager service, which could then be responsible for setting the nickname on the accounts.

In this context, you don't *really* have to override either `equals` or `hashCode` since that's not going to give you what you want anyway; you won't always have two otherwise identical accounts with the same nickname, and bastardizing the `equals` method to pay attention to a single field feels *wrong*.

First things first - let's start with a simple account manager.  This makes use of collections and streams, concepts which for brevity I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.

The mechanics are straightforward:

- If we have an account which has the nickname, we don't update it.  If we don't, we update it by ID.
- This service is now responsible for creating and manipulating all accounts.

```
public class AccountManager {

    final List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Account createAccount(String id, String name, String type) {
        Account account = new Account(id, name, type);
        accounts.add(account);
        return account;
    }

    public boolean setNickName(String id, String nickName) {
        Optional<Account> existingAccount = accounts.stream()
                                    .firstMatch(a -> a.getNickName().equals(nickName));
        if(existingAccount.isPresent()) {
            return false; // don't allow modification to an account who has the same nickname
        } else {
            accounts.stream()
                    .firstMatch(a -> a.getId().equals(id))
                    .ifPresent(a -> a.setNickName(nickName));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, with this class, you should get what you want - any account managed by the `AccountManager` won't be able to have the same nickname.